# Declaring buttons in Action script code

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, actionscript, mxml, mxmlc

How to declare the buttons in the following AS code What is the library that needs to be included

```
package
{

    public class caml extends Sprite
    {

       public function buttons()
       {
         saveButton.visible = false;
         discardButton.visible = false;

       }
       private function captureImage(e:MouseEvent):void
       {
         capture.visible = false;
         saveButton.visible = true;
         discardButton.visible = true;
       }

    }   

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you mean buttons as in the Flash IDE and not the component one, these are [SimpleButton](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/SimpleButton.html)

```
package {
 import flash.display.SimpleButton;
 public class caml extends Sprite {
   public var saveButton:SimpleButton;
   //...
 }
}
```

Comment: Alert() sounds like a custom class, that depends on where you put the class?